# The symbolism of Mike Ross's bike

Tags: character, suits

What is the symbolism with Mike Ross using a bicycle to get to work? Initially I thought Mike used a bike because he didn't want to spend the money on transportation, and the bike was a hold over from his bike messenger days. Then I noticed that he adopted a car service when he accepted the job as an investment banker. They point this out when Rachel asks if she can use his car to get to school. Maybe the car was a perk of that job but he didn't use his bike again after he was rehired by the law firm as an associate. The only time we see him use his bike again is when they made a point to show him get his bike out of a closet when he went to see the priest for the first time.

Also after I started thinking about the bicycle I noticed in the opening credit reel they show Harvey getting out of his town car while looking through a bicycle wheel. This seems to be subtly contrasting Harvey with Mike, but I don't fully understand the symbolism that the bike and the credits represent.

Answer (score 1):

This is a contrast, and shows how Mike changes.  As Mike becomes more like Harvey he adopts more of Harvey's things, the car (rather than the bike), and even his hair changes to be more Harvey like.

When Mike goes to prison, we see that change back implying he's no longer trying to be either a lawyer or Harvey.

Comment: How was being an investment banker significant enough in Mike's journey to be like Harvey to mark it with the car? I agree Mike does transition to being more Harvey like throughout the show. Your answer helped me understand the credits symbolism as transitioning from where he was to where he wants to be. Bike messenger to powerful attorney. I'm waiting for Season 6 to come to Amazon Prime since I don't have cable. I'm looking forward to the next evolution you mentioned